# Why are my variables not getting swapped?

Tags: java, object, oop

I want to swap variables a & b. Here's the output : [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUm8e.png)

The variables are swapped inside the parent function but not outside of it

```
public class SwapNumbers{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Swap sw = new Swap();
        int a = 10;
        int b = 65;
        sw.a = a;
        sw.b = b;
        sw.swap(sw.a, sw.b);
        sw.display(sw.a, sw.b);
    }
}

class Swap{
    int a, b;
    void swap(int a, int b){
        int temp = a;
        a = b; 
        b = temp;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
    void display(int a, int b){
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

How can I modify them into global for Swap class? I tried accessing them using the object itself but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to have `a` and `b` as fields, and to pass them as variables as well. If you remove the `int a, int b` from `swap(int a, int b)` (and also don't pass them when you call the method), it should work.

Comment: Why does the `Swap` class need class-level fields for `a` and `b` that it never uses?  Or, conversely, why does the `swap` method need `a` and `b` parameters if the class already has those values?  It sounds like you need to pick one approach or the other, currently you're mixing both.

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework?  It's possible you are being asked to do something like this:

```
class Swap{
    int a, b;
    void swap(){
        int temp = a;
        a = b; 
        b = temp;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

So that:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Swap sw = new Swap();
    int a = 10;
    int b = 65;
    sw.a = a;
    sw.b = b;
    sw.swap();
    sw.display();
}
```

The idea is to swap the fields, not pass them into the method.  See the comment above about pass by reference vs pass by value.  You actually can't do it with method parameters, that's why you're being asked to do it this way.